# The plugin SkidSteerDrivePlugin did not work on pioneer3at model in gazebo 5

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,all:
I added the plugin in pioneer3at model like this:

```
   <model name='pioneer3at'>
      ...
      <static>0</static>
      ...
      <plugin name='SkidSteerDrivePlugin' filename='libSkidSteerDrivePlugin.so'>
        <right_front>right_front</right_front>
        <right_rear>right_rear</right_rear>
        <left_front>left_front</left_front>
        <left_rear>left_rear</left_rear>
        <MaxForce>5.0</MaxForce>
      </plugin>
    </model>
```

But when I run the gazebo and then publish topic'~/pioneer3at/vel_cmd' using rqt_gui, the pioneer did not move.Also, any possible topic name has been tried.
Anyone know why the pioneer did not move?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13303/the-plugin-skidsteerdriveplugin-did-not-work-on-pioneer3at-model-in-gazebo-5/) by [Dengqing](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2602/dengqing/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using `rqt_gui`, you're probably trying to publish to ROS topics, rather than Gazebo topics, which is what your plugin is subscribed to.

You can check the list of Gazebo topics with active publishers/subscribers with `gz topic -l`, and the list of ROS topics with `rostopic list`.

You can try writing a Gazebo publisher like [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/deb0665b2f18/examples/stand_alone/publisher/?at=default).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dengqing](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2602/dengqing/) on 2016-05-18**:
It works! Thanks!